# When do we use "speaking of which", "by the way" and "anyway"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, phrase-usage, phrases

Context: Mike and Mary talked about politics and war then they talked about Bob's wedding, then talked about gifts, then talked about mom, then ed the conversation

> Mary: I hate war
>
> Mike: ....talk about politics and war...
>
> Mary: **Speaking of which / by the way / anyway**, we're going to Bob's
> wedding this weekend (**1**)
>
> Mike: ...talk about Bob's wedding...
>
> Mary: **Speaking of which / by the way / anyway**, have you bought any
> gift for him? (**2**)
>
> Mike: ... talk about the wedding gift...
>
> Mary: **Speaking of which / by the way / anyway**, how is your mom going? (**3**)
>
> Mike: ... talk about the mom....
>
> Mary: **Speaking of which / by the way / anyway**, I have to leave now
> (end conversation) (**4**)

Do we use "**Speaking of which**" or "**by the way**" or "**anyway**" in sentence 1,2,3,4?

**When do we use "speaking of which", "by the way" and "anyway"?**

Comment: As Astralbee implies, 'speaking of which' is appropriate _only_ at (2) (going from the wedding to wedding presents). The others are a complete change of subject. Mary might say at (1) "To speak of more cheerful topics..."

Answer (score 1):

'Speaking of which...' requires you to have been speaking about, or at least mentioned the subject you are about talk about further. For example, if somebody's name was mentioned in passing and you now wish to use the moment to talk about them in more detail.

'By the way' introduces any incidental statement - it could be completely tangential to what you were speaking about. It could be parenthetical information to what you are speaking about, or something unrelated but timely in some other way.

So, there is some similarity in the *way* the above two phrases are used, but they are different. But 'anyway' is not used the same way as these at all. It is used in the same way as the word 'regardless', to resume talking about a subject after a brief aside or to partially dismiss what has been said as not relevant to (or not affecting) what you are about to say.